# Java: How to extend a inner class from different file

Tags: java, inner-classes, extends, implements

say I have these two classes in a single file where class A is a top level class:

```
class A{
     class B{
     } 
}
```

how to make another top level class, say class C, extend class B without making B static?

Comment: You need to make B static. Due to your hesitancy, I am guessing that you may have an incorrect understanding of what a static inner class is. Why don't you want B to be static?

Comment: Are you asking for something like `class C extends A.B{ public C(A a){ a.super(); } }`? Note that any instance of inner class (B) requires instance of outer class (A) to exist. Same rule is forced on any subtype of B (here C). You can either provide instance of A via argument in constructor, or you can create it explicitly like `class C extends A.B{ public C(){new A().super();}}`.  BTW I am assuming that you have direct access to that inner class (for instance it is not private)

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=x-y+problem&oq=x-Y+problem) ?